# TFS build agent can not access TFS 2015 server from different environment

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to set up a build server (vNext) after upgrading to TFS 2015.

I followed the MS step-by-step guide and everything was setup correctly, but the agent is getting a "**You are not authorized to access http://xxxxx:8080**", but the agent is running on a different server in another environment.

Here is the situation ...

1. I have a On-primises TFS 2015 with update 1 in production environment.
2. I installed TFS build agent on a server in our development environment, which connecting to TFS in production. Not sure the prod username & password is saved?
3. The agent is running as windows service with a doamin account from development environment.
4. When i start the service i'm getting the above mentioned error.

So how can I run the TFS build agent with dev domain account and use another prod account to connect to TFS to get data?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Log On credential of the build service to use production domain account after the build service is installed:

1. Run services.msc to open Service manager.
2. Find and open the build service.
3. Enter the production domain account credential under the "Log On" tab of the build service.
4. Restart the build service.

Comment: Hi Eddie, The problem is that I can't do that because there is no domain trust between dev and prod environment. My problem is that I have to run the build agent with a dev account, but need to connecto to TFS using prod account. Can I solve this by adding any logon parameter in the agent config.. if yes.. please show some sample...

Comment: @Balatharan Did you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026380/how-to-authenticate-build-vnext-agent-to-on-premise-tfs?

Comment: Hi Eddie.. Thanks for the link.. i have seen it and tried it.. but with no luck.. maybe I could have made some mistaske.. I will give it a second try.. but the main problem is that i have to run the agent as a Windows Service!

Comment: Hi Eddie, I tried the link and it working now, but the problem is that I can't run the agent with lokal account, the build agent most run as domain user do to other dependencies with other system. We have some unittest that uses database, file share, etc. So it it possible to add a different logon info in the agent config file?

Comment: @Balatharan There isn't any way to do this as I know. You can submit a feature request on VSTS User Voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services. The workaround I know for your scenario is using the shadow account or trust the domain.

Comment: @Balatharan I just remembered that you can also configure the build agent via command parameters that allow you to specify the login account. You can try with this command to configure it: ""Agent\VsoAgent.exe" /configure /RunningAsService /ServerUrl:"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs" /Name:AgentName /PoolName:PoolName /Login:UserName,Password;AuthType=AAD /force /workfolder:"X:\xxx\xxx" /WindowsServiceLogonAccount:"Username" /WindowsServiceLogonPassword:"Password"". Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/agents/windows#Command_lineparameters.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT maybe you should update the answer to include the information from this last comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the build service under a user account that has TFS access.

That worked for me. Click on the properties of the build service and change the  user account it runs as.

Hope that helps.