# TFS Build Agent Pool: Error Connecting The Server

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, build-automation, agent

### TFS Build Agent Pool Setup Error:

- I am trying to setup an agent pool on a server on a domain to connect to the TFS which in another domain,

## Expected:

A prompt appear to enter the Authentication for the user name & Password for the TFS

## What Happen: Error:

Error Connecting The Server, An error occurred while sending the request.

## The PowerShell Script:

> PS C:\agent> .\ConfigureAgent
>   An existing configuration file was detected.  This will update the local agent settings.  Do you want to also replace th
>   e server registration (default is N)? n
>   Enter the name for this agent (default is Agent-UKWTSVULM768) -------
>   Enter the URL for the Team Foundation Server (default is ) https://tfspro.-----.-------.net/tfs
>   Configure this agent against which agent pool? (default pool name is 'default')
>   Enter the path of the work folder for this agent (default is 'C:\agent_work')
>   Would you like to install the agent as a Windows Service (Y/N) (default is N) n
>   ErrorConnectingToTheServer
>   An error occurred while sending the request.
>   PS C:\agent>

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my side to deploy a build agent cross domain. After enter the TFS domain username and password, I got a TF14045 error.

[image]

[image]

After seeing this error, run `.\RunAgent.cmd`, you'll see the agent register successfully.

Another way you can try is to create a shadow account like case [How to authenticate build.vnext agent to on-premise TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026380/how-to-authenticate-build-vnext-agent-to-on-premise-tfs) do.