# Deployment of Windows Services on Remote Servers (Different Domain)

Tags: powershell, deployment, tfs, windows-services

Is there a simpler way of deploying Windows Services from TFS than using a Powershell script, run on the TFS server, which:

1. Stops the existing Windows Service on the remote server
2. Copy the file on a shared folder on the remote server (copy-item)
3. Starts the Windows Service on the remote

If not, can any other continuous integration/deployment tool do this better?

As the TFS server is using a domain controller which is different from the remote server, can we share a folder for a specific user? I tried to run the powershell script as a user from the target domain controller, but of course, it is not recognized as a valid user on TFS server.

At last, is there any difference on deploying on an hosted remote server or on the cloud?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In [tasks based build system](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/create) (TFS 2015 +), you can try to install [Windows Service Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.windows-service-release-tasks), which contains tasks to start and stop windows services as well as change the startup type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was not aware of this tool and I will give it a try as it looks very clean. I was hoping they will be a single component to do all this - to me, it looks like it is a quite common thing to deploy windows services and that it should as easy as web deployment. Any ideas for the other questions?

Comment: You can deploy a build agent cross domain by following case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026380/how-to-authenticate-build-vnext-agent-to-on-premise-tfs